# Cygwin SSH connection issue to BitBucket

Tags: git, ssh, cygwin

Can you help with this Access Denied issue (Cygwin SSH BitBucket)

I have copied my public key across to BitBucket.

When I run the following **ssh -vvvT git@github.com** the output is...

When I try to push code to BitBucket the command just hangs.

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1h 5 Jun 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.252.131] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/David/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/David/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/David/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/David/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/David/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/David/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/David/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/David/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/David/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh-0.6.0
debug1: no match: libssh-0.6.0
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "github.com" from file "/home/David/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/David/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.c                                                                                                                            om,ssh-rsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha                                                                                                                            2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-grou                                                                                                                            p14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha                                                                                                                            2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@                                                                                                                            openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com                                                                                                                            ,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.c                                                                                                                            om,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,a                                                                                                                            es192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.c                                                                                                                            om,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,a                                                                                                                            es192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,                                                                                                                            umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-et                                                                                                                            m@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@open                                                                                                                            ssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hma                                                                                                                            c-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,                                                                                                                            umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-et                                                                                                                            m@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@open                                                                                                                            ssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hma                                                                                                                            c-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-dss,ssh-rsa
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,blowfish-                                                                                                                            cbc,3des-cbc,des-cbc-ssh1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,blowfish-                                                                                                                            cbc,3des-cbc,des-cbc-ssh1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "github.com" from file "/home/David/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/David/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "192.30.252.131" from file "/home/David/.ssh/known_hos                                                                                                                            ts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/David/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/David/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/David/.ssh/id_rsa (0x80061f38),
debug2: key: /home/David/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0),
debug2: key: /home/David/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0x0),
debug2: key: /home/David/.ssh/id_ed25519 (0x0),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/David/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/David/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/David/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/David/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/David/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/David/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/David/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: ssh -i <publickey> <username>@<hostname>

Comment: @nafas do I paste the public key in the place holder as stated?

Comment: Update... 

After some debugging I got the following output...
`code`
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1h 5 Jun 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
ssh: Could not resolve hostname git: Name or service not known....

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Ok Fixed this

Solution...

Install Cygwin Git even if you have GIT installed and its initializing a repo ok. Not sure if this is necessary but got more relevant debugging info after this step.

I then did the following GIT PUSH and got the following error...

```
$ git push
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0660 for '/home/David/.ssh/id_rsa' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
bad permissions: ignore key: /home/David/.ssh/id_rsa
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Even changing the private key permissions did not fix this. It appears Windows 8 has an issue with groups or none assigned groups. So I needed to set a group on the private key then change perms to 600.

```
$ cd ~/.ssh/ 

$ chgrp Users id_rsa

$ chmod 600 id_rsa
```

TaDa!!! Working.